# Why is this SQL trigger failing to be saved

Tags: sql, triggers

I am trying to create a simple trigger to update the season column in table `energydata_temp` based on the month of a timestamp column.

Despite selecting the column from the dropdown list proposed by HeidiSQL, I get an error about column name `eTimestamp` being unknown in column list. The column does exists with the exact same spelling.

Any ideas why this is failing?

Here is the complete SQL statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `energydata_temp_after_insert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `energydata_temp` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF month(energydata_temp.eTimestamp) IN (12, 1, 2) THEN
        SET energydata_temp.season = 1
    ELSEIF month(energydata_temp.eTimestamp) IN (3, 4, 5) THEN
        SET energydata_temp.season = 2
    ELSEIF month(energydata_temp.eTimestamp) IN (6, 7, 8) THEN
        SET energydata_temp.season = 3
    ELSEIF month(energydata_temp.eTimestamp) IN (9, 10, 11) THEN
        SET energydata_temp.season = 4
    END IF;
END;
```

> SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'eTimestamp' in 'field list'

Cheers,
Gaetano.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's usually a mistake to *store* data that can be *calculated* from existing data. That just opens you up to the possibility of inconsistencies - for instance, currently if something updates `eTimestamp` later, your season column can be incorrect. If, instead, you calculate season when *retrieving* data from the database, it will always be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll get to the column next, but the trigger should be a `BEFORE INSERT`, because with `AFTER INSERT`, the insert is already done. After insert would be to, say, insert/update to another table. Within the SQL to another table, then you would use the typical column names as usual.

So, to the column:

With triggers, you don't refer to the columns directly by name, but from the `NEW` or `OLD` references. With before update, you can change the NEW references.

Try this instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `energydata_temp_after_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `energydata_temp` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF month(NEW.eTimestamp) IN (12,1,2) THEN
        SET NEW.season = 1;
    ELSEIF month(NEW.eTimestamp) IN (3,4,5) THEN
        SET NEW.season = 2;
    ELSEIF month(NEW.eTimestamp) IN (6,7,8) THEN
        SET NEW.season = 3;
    ELSEIF month(NEW.eTimestamp) IN (9,10,11) THEN
        SET NEW.season = 4;
    END IF;
END;
```

I created this minimal structure to test the trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE `energydata_temp` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `eTimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `season` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here's output from query interaction:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from energydata_temp;
+----+---------------------+--------+
| id | eTimestamp          | season |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-10-14 20:20:35 |      4 |
|  2 | 2020-10-14 20:20:54 |      4 |
|  3 | 2020-07-03 00:00:00 |      3 |
+----+---------------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into energydata_temp(eTimestamp) values ('2020-02-21');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from energydata_temp;
+----+---------------------+--------+
| id | eTimestamp          | season |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-10-14 20:20:35 |      4 |
|  2 | 2020-10-14 20:20:54 |      4 |
|  3 | 2020-07-03 00:00:00 |      3 |
|  4 | 2020-02-21 00:00:00 |      1 |
+----+---------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into energydata_temp(eTimestamp) values (NOW());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from energydata_temp;
+----+---------------------+--------+
| id | eTimestamp          | season |
+----+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | 2020-10-14 20:20:35 |      4 |
|  2 | 2020-10-14 20:20:54 |      4 |
|  3 | 2020-07-03 00:00:00 |      3 |
|  4 | 2020-02-21 00:00:00 |      1 |
|  5 | 2020-10-14 20:39:15 |      4 |
+----+---------------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It works now. My SQL knowledge used to be limited to select+conditions in localSQL to get a rowset in dBase. Now I find myself doing more and more in SQL because I use MySQL as a backend database for a web app.